# Add vertical and horizontal line to a div (representing a bracket) using selectors of CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm doing a design using HTML & CSS to represent that I'm doing a calculation with the data that will be entered on the fields.

**What I want to achieve:**

[image]

**What I have tried:**

```css
.bracket-dividers {
  border-left: 4px solid #000;
  border-right: 4px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.bracket-dividers:before {
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.bracket-dividers:after {
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.plus-symbol {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.plus-symbol::before {
  content: '+';
}
```

```html
<div class="bracket-dividers">
   <div>
      Field 1
   </div>
   <span class="plus-symbol"></span>
   <div>
      Field 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Issues In the example above:

1. if I copy-paste the `.bracket-dividers:before` and `.bracket-dividers:after` but changing the position (right & top = 0, right & bottom = 0), causes that the horizontal lines of the left side disappear. Maybe we cannot have more than 1 `before/after` selector?
2. I try to apply `margin` or `padding` to the content inside but, don't work. Seems that the selectors don't allow this.

My goal is to apply the vertical and horizontal lines on both sides to a div and apply a space inside for the content (margin or padding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot define multiple pseudo-elements (`::before` / `::after`) for a single element.

Instead, imagine using the `::before` pseudo-element for the left bracket and the `::after` pseudo-element for the right bracket.

The left bracket is an element with top, left and bottom borders defined, while the right bracket is an element with the top, right and bottom borders defined.

Example:

```css
.bracket-dividers {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height: 35px;
  
  padding: 30px; /* Extra padding works correctly! */
}

.bracket-dividers:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-right: 0;
}

.bracket-dividers:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-left: 0;
}

.plus-symbol {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.plus-symbol::before {
  content: '+';
}
```

```html
<div class="bracket-dividers">
   <div>
      Field 1
   </div>
   <span class="plus-symbol"></span>
   <div>
      Field 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A border-image can do it:

```css
.bracket-dividers {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-image:linear-gradient(to right,#000 10px,transparent 0 calc(100% - 10px),#000 0) 4;
  padding:10px;
  display: inline-flex;
}


.plus-symbol {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.plus-symbol::before {
  content: '+';
}
```

```html
<div class="bracket-dividers">
   <div>
      Field 1
   </div>
   <span class="plus-symbol"></span>
   <div>
      Field 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly too. Don't know 100% how did you accomplish the lines with just using `border-image` and `linear-gradient`, awesome skills you have.

Comment: @RRGT19 it's not that complicated ;) it's a gradient with 3 coloration (black, transparent, black) that you apply to only on the border part